# LESS How to change a progress bar background color when it reaches 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

Hi I'm just getting started with LESS, CSS, Javascript, and HTML as I a building a website. I was wondering if it was possible to use LESS to check to see if the width of an element is 100% and once it is change the background color. Like a progress bar being completed. If it's not possible would I use Javascript? Where would I define that statement using the example:

```
.page-level-progress-menu-item-indicator-bar {
        width:0%;
        height:8px;
        background-color:@primary-color;
    }
```

Javascript function:

```
updateProgressBar: function() {
            if (this.model.get('completedChildrenAsPercentage')) {
                var percentageOfCompleteComponents = this.model.get('completedChildrenAsPercentage');
            } else {
                var percentageOfCompleteComponents = 0;
            }

            // Add percentage of completed components as an aria label attribute
            this.$('.page-level-progress-menu-item-indicator-bar .aria-label').html(this.ariaText + Math.floor(percentageOfCompleteComponents) + '%');


        },
```

HTML:

```
<div class="page-level-progress-menu-item-indicator">
    <div id ="test" class="page-level-progress-menu-item-indicator-bar" style="width:{{completedChildrenAsPercentage}}%"><span class="aria-label" role="region" tabindex="0"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not really how CSS works. CSS is declarative, and the notion of "checking" element size doesn't make much sense.

Comment: LESS is a `pre-processor` for CSS. CSS is a set of rules that get applied to a document and does not hold any information about the structure of the document. For that task you will need to use JavaScript (or jQuery - which is a JavaScript library), after the page has been loaded.

Comment: I guess you're already using JS to increase your progress bar width, so I'd suggest you to add a class **full** via JS when you reach 100%. Use this `.full` to change the `background-color` in your LESS.

Comment: I added the javascript function to the main post. Would I do something like if percentage = "100" then .addClass .full to the correct class?

Comment: paste your progress bar html code too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LESS and CSS are not built to perform such a task. CSS rules are set before your page is loaded. you have to do that with javascript.

here is a simple example written on the fly. you can use its idea or personalize the example itself.

```js
var innerWidth = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if($(".inner-progress").width() >= $(".progress-bar").width()) {
    $(".inner-progress").addClass("completed");
    clearInterval(interval);
  } else {
   innerWidth = $(".inner-progress").width();
    innerWidth += $(".progress-bar").width() / 100;
    $(".inner-progress").width(innerWidth + "px");
  }
}, 10);
```

```css
.progress-bar, .inner-progress {
  height: 30px;
}
.progress-bar {
  background: grey;
}
.inner-progress {
  background: red;
  width: 10%;
}
.completed {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="inner-progress">
  </div>
</div>
```